# Polynomial multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a function Q(x) only has integer coefficients and has factors : f<sub>1</sub>(x),f<sub>2</sub>(x),... f<sub>n</sub>(x). Can the functions f<sub>1</sub>(x),f<sub>2</sub>(x),... and f<sub>n</sub>(x) necessarily have integer coefficients?

Gaussian integers are fine for functions with complex roots.

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is "of course not".  For example, $x^2-1$ has integer coefficients but we can factorise it as
$$x^2-1=(71x-71)({\textstyle\frac{1}{71}}x+{\textstyle\frac{1}{71}})\ ,$$
and the second factor does not have integer coefficients.  But the point here is that we are just deliberately making things difficult, and we could adjust this by taking $71$ out of the first factor and putting it into the second,
$$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)\ ,$$
so that we have factors with integer coefficients.

If a polynomial with integer coefficients is factorised as a product of polynomials with rational coefficients, then the factorisation can always be adjusted in a similar way: this is a corollary of [Gauss' Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29).

Comment: That's not the point that I was trying to get across but I think, I'm wrong nonetheless. 

x^2-3 =f(x) for example
f(x)=(x-sqrt(3))(x+sqrt(3)).